# How to retrieve data from Google Spreadsheet to Javascript or JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

This is public spreadsheet created using Google Drive: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hA4LKZn9yKoqnSzaI6_73GQSj_ZVpB3O0kC93QM98Vs/pubhtml

How to retrieve data from Google Spreadsheet to Javascript or JSON with new [Google Spreadsheets API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) ?

Comment: [See here for detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26774243/1922144)

Comment: Could you help me in the following problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023533/is-there-any-way-to-have-google-sheets-cell-values-as-dynamic-variable-into-a-js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access a [cell-based basic feed](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_a_cell-based_feed) using the following URL structure:  https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1hA4LKZn9yKoqnSzaI6_73GQSj_ZVpB3O0kC93QM98Vs/od6/public/basic?alt=json .  By default the feed is in XML form, however, you can request JSON format using alt=json query parameter.

This feed also supports JSONP requests, so an example of fetching this data from a browser with jQuery might look like:

```
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1hA4LKZn9yKoqnSzaI6_73GQSj_ZVpB3O0kC93QM98Vs/od6/public/basic?alt=json";
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success:function(data) {
        // data.feed.entry is an array of objects that represent each cell
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If, alternatively, you want to keep it all in the Google environment. if you're looking for a more controlled JSON generator, check out this gist:

[JSONPuller](https://gist.github.com/jalcantarab/0eb43b13c97e4f784bd0be327f6ced52)

It takes in a Spreadsheet sheet and returns an array of objects, with the row that you decide as the key (defaults to whichever row is frozen)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using [opensheet](https://github.com/benborgers/opensheet).

Steps:

1. Make sure the sheet as read access - Anyone with the link can view it.
2. Sheet should have First row as Header row with titles
3. Then get the sheet data as json using the following link - `https://opensheet.elk.sh/spreadsheet_id/sheet_name`
4. Replace `spreadsheet_id` with your sheet id and `sheet_name` with your sheet name. No authentication is required.